# How to angularjs write log to file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging, log4javascript

I have a question? In Angularjs project, what log I can use to write to file? $log of Angular or log4javascript.
I have code config for $log of Angularjs:

```
$log.getInstance = function (context) {
        return {
            log: enhanceLogging($log.log, context),
            info: enhanceLogging($log.info, context),
            warn: enhanceLogging($log.warn, context),
            debug: enhanceLogging($log.debug, context),
            error: enhanceLogging($log.error, context)
        };
    };

    function enhanceLogging(loggingFunc, context) {
        return function () {
            var modifiedArguments = [].slice.call(arguments);
            modifiedArguments[0] = [moment().format("dddd h:mm:ss a") + '::[' + context + ']: '] + modifiedArguments[0];
            loggingFunc.apply(null, modifiedArguments);
        };
    }
```

It's working but it only write to console and now I want log output to file?

Comment: If you want to log it into files, you have to send the logs to an API which will write the logs into files.

Answer (score 2):

Clientside Javascript does not have access to files on disk. So it is impossible to write to a logfile.

However you could use something like [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/for/javascript/) to log your messages.

Comment: Thank you, I will send log to server and server write it :)